# Single Word : Cannot be resolved by waiting and trying again

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means an issue cannot be resolved by waiting and trying again. Essentially the opposite of intermittent or temporary.

I would previously have used systemic or systematic, but checking the dictionary definitions of these having been challenged on them neither seems to quite fit.

Update to answer questions in the comments:

The word I'm looking for should reflect a problem that will persist until external action is taken, but is not necessarily urgent.

To use it in a sentence:

> "Your request has encountered a {Special Word} problem, and will not
>   be retried."

The use I'll be putting it to is more in the nature of a column header though. On the one hand there are temporary problems that might go away if we try again shortly, on the other hand are these problems.

Comment: Hello, Jontia. Do you mean that the problem is so serious that it must be addressed at once? Or permanent (until solved)?

Comment: Just that it is permanent until solved, not necessarily the same as urgent.

Comment: *Perennial* problem?

Comment: Does the word "irremediable" convey the point you'd like the warning to make?

Comment: "problem that will persist until external action is taken" -> **persistent** problem?

Comment: deadlock? it certainly implies that waiting will not make it possible.

Comment: I suggest there's ain't no such animal, which is why 14 Answers and five Comments have merely made themselves into examples…

Particularly with an example such as ”Your request has encountered a {Special Word} problem, and will not be retried" it seems fairly clear you’re talking about an IT system and then about a “real” problem, as opposed to one of access.

Most obviously “The server might be down” might be resolved by trying again but “The parameter is not recognised” will not.

Comment: You are asking this question because you don't know what word to use. But you're somehow expecting that when you use the word (once found), that the user will be perfectly able to understand what you mean by it? That seems a bit iffy. Don't look for a highly specialized word with a precisely defined meaning, because you'll have to expect your users to be familiar with the word and its exact definition. Instead, use common English to explain the situation to the user. Being verbose and clear is better than being terse and vague.

Comment: (afterthought to above comment) Being terse _and_ clear is of course ideal. But if you have to pick one, pick "clear" over "terse".

Comment: True, but as @RobbieGoodwin spotted the source of the query is an IT system. Specifically its the name of a boolean variable in a status object. Only the developers need to understand it and this whole thing started when someone didn't like the word I was currently using. Being clear is still important, but verbosity should be avoided in the variable name, it can of course go in the comments.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

> "Your request has encountered a **structural** problem, and will not
>   be retried."

**structural**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/structural)* and [TFD - Encyclopedia](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/structural)**

> *resulting from the existing political, legal or economic structure
>   **structural :social class, religion, gender, ethnicity, customs, etc. that can limit or influence individual opportunities.

Comment: If a computer system said this to me, I would assume very strongly that the person who had written the message was not a native speaker of English. Yes, 'structural' can have this meaning. But no, this is not a good error message.

Comment: For me this message would imply that there was a problem with the structure of my request.

Comment: @AakashM, which one would you recommend then?

Comment: My favourite *answer* is [KRyan's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440881/12988). Although if you must have a *single* word, [I think you already had the answer yourself](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440744/single-word-cannot-be-resolved-by-waiting-and-trying-again/440817#comment1058112_440744)...

Comment: I understand. And in all fairness I'm not intending to use it as a message, the sentence example is only in the question because somebody asked for it. The actual use case is categorisation/grouping rather than friendly messages, which is why I want a single word.

Comment: Obviously I like and defend this answer. Structural problems vary. It is not just a computer 'blue screen of death' problem. I do not think OP intended for this to be a error message. Those suggestions that OP re-write her question are not germane. That can be approached by new questions posed by ... well anyone.

Comment: We welcome your answer. Give it your best shot. Then, let it go and move on. This is not a forum for argument.

Comment: In my experience, this structure is called "architecture" in IT, but I don't think "architectural" is the ideal solution to the original question.

Answer (score 27):

> "Your request has encountered an ***unrecoverable*** problem, and will not
>   be retried."

ODO:

> **[unrecoverable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unrecoverable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   Not able to be recovered or corrected.
>
> ‘any sudden power failure can cause unrecoverable file and disc
>   errors’

Techopedia:

> *[**Unrecoverable** Error](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/13453/unrecoverable-error)*
>
> An unrecoverable error is an error that occurs during the execution of
>   a code or a program that has not been registered before and **no retries
>   can correct or undo the error**.

Comment: The question says that it can be solved, but by external forces (ie. it doesn't solves by itself).

Answer (score 24):

You should reword this wording altogether; none of the options here state unambiguously what you mean, and it is unlikely that any user reading this message with any of those examples will understand what you mean. Something like

> Your request has encountered a problem this program cannot resolve, and it will not be retried.

This is far clearer than any single-word option available to slot into the sample sentence. Better still would be to suggest steps the user can take to remedy the situation, the more specific the better (but they have to be relevant—I can’t tell you how annoying it is for my personal Windows computer to tell me to talk to my network administrator).

Comment: I think this is the most realistic answer.  The message should also tell the user what to do, e.g., contact their systems administrator, email help@foo.com, try again tomorrow, or whatever.

Answer (score 17):

In software development this is referred to as a ***fatal error***.

I have not encountered a fatal problem.

Problems (due to hanging or crashing) tend to be *irreconcilable*.

Comment: Came to recommend '_terminal_' error, but I think your's is synonymous.

Comment: As OP states the problem is neither terminal or fatal.

Comment: @lbf Can I get you to re-read the second sentence? What does that tell you?

Comment: a problem's whose solution will not be found quickly...but will be resolved when various structural barrier(s) are surmounted.

Comment: @lbf No. The question does not suggest your interpretation. The application is a column header/title for a category of related issues. Few of us agree with your answer notwithstanding your passionate defence.

Comment: A fatal error kills the application. There is no indication that this error kills the application, just that the particular action the user took could not be completed, and without external changes, won’t be possible.

Comment: @KRyan The intended application of our answers not the "software program" kind of application. You have misinterpreted the meaning of the word in the poster's context. I made no reference to the particular software being tested.

Comment: @Stan “The word I'm looking for should reflect a problem that will persist until external action is taken, but is not necessarily urgent.” *Fatal* meets neither of those criteria.

Comment: @KRyan If I agreed with you, we'd both be wrong. Oh, look, there's my bus. I gotta go.

Comment: "fatal" has a very specific meaning in IT terms. A fatal error is one that is so massive that the computer/application is incapable of handling it. A fatal application error is an error that causes the application to exit. The fact that OP's application is **showing an error message** means it's handling the error, and therefore the error is **not fatal**.

Comment: As to your claim that _"The intended application of our answers not the "software program" kind of application."_; while it is true that answers here should not rely on jargon; that does not give you a free pass to start redefining jargon based on general English definitions. Your answer is not a good answer because it _collides_ with a pre-existing definition of the word "fatal", **regardless** of what "fatal" means in general English.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest **persistent** or **chronic**.

From Merriam-Webster:

---

- [persistent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persistent)
- 1 : existing for a long or longer than usual time or continuously
- 2: continuing or inclined to persist in a course

---

- [chronic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronic)
- 1 : continuing or occurring again and again for a long time
- 2 : always present or encountered

Comment: Persistent suggests that I've already retried it and have given up, but the nature of the problem means there is no point retrying. Chronic has similar issues for my use case.

Comment: Something more like *recurrent* then?

Comment: In medicine, a "chronic illness" is one that continues indefinitely.  In general, "chronic" doesn't mean it went away and came back; it means it stayed where it was. "Recurring" would be something that goes away and comes back.

Comment: @Jay _"In general, "chronic" doesn't mean it went away and came back;"_ To extend your comment: "intermittent" is the word that means "it repeatedly went away and came back"

Answer (score 6):

## [irresolvable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irresolvable)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> (of a problem or dilemma) impossible to solve or settle.
> -OLD

Comment: The question says that it can be solved, but by external forces (ie. it doesn't solves by itself).

Comment: @Braiam: Therefore, the problem is irresolvable **in scope of the application**. If my computer tells me that there is no internet connection, it's referring to its own internet connection, not making an absolute statement about the entire world. Similarly, an application error message is always implicitily in scope of the application itself. Since the problem cannot be solved by the application, the application is therefore correct when it reports that it has encountered an irresolvable error.

Answer (score 3):

Use the opposite word of *resolvable* which is [**unresolvable**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unresolvable):

> not able to be resolved or brought to a satisfactory resolution

Your example:

> Your request has encountered a **unresolvable** problem, and will not be retried.

Comment: OP: it is resolvable.

Answer (score 1):

### impasse

Implying that there are external conditions which *are combining with* internal conditions to make continuation impossible.

Impasse implies problem, so your sentence would be

> "Your request has encountered an **impasse**, and will not be retried [automatically]."

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for might be [intrinsic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intrinsic) or [inherent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inherent)

> *intrinsic*
>
> belonging to a thing by its very nature
>
> *inherent*
>
> existing in someone or something as a permanent and inseparable element, quality, or attribute

Examples:

> Your request has encountered an *intrinsic* problem, and will not be retried.
>
> Your request has encountered an *inherent* problem, and will not be retried.

Answer (score 0):

How about "unsalvageable"?  It implies that there is no use in retrying.  This carries less of an implication than "fatal" or "terminal" that the problem's nature is of a kind where human intervention would not help either.

If you want to make the distinction stronger, I don't see that you can make do with a single word reliably, but something like "not automatically salvageable" will be quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going with your gut instinct, which is

> Essentially the opposite of intermittent or temporary.

Why not name the columns **Temporary** and **Non-Temporary**?

That gives users a clear understanding of what is in that column. While it might not be the prettiest English word, Non-Temporary is often used in official contexts such as [Non-Temporary Storage in the US military](https://www.sddc.army.mil/pp/Pages/nts.aspx), or [Non-Temporary 
purpose of stay for a Netherlands Visa](http://ind.nl/en/Pages/temporary-and-non-temporary-purposes-of-stay.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Given this part of the question:

> The word I'm looking for should reflect a problem that will **persist until external action is taken**, but is not necessarily urgent.

I would choose **exogenous**, according to [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exogenous):

> Having an external cause or origin.

In your example:

> "Your request has encountered an **exogenous** problem, and will not be retried."

Attribution: "Exogenous | Definition of Exogenous in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 09, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exogenous.

Comment: As slightly simpler words getting a similar point across, **external** or **extrinsic** might also be good alternatives (since *exogenous* is unusual enough that many people might not understand it).

Comment: The problem with external and similar suggestions is that some external problems are temporary and some are {this}.

Comment: I'd avoid exogenous simply because most people probably wont know what it means.  Error messages should be explanatory, and should typically not require a user to pull out their dictionary to look up the word...

Answer (score -1):

I suggest:

> Your request is **blocked** and will not be retried.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this as it could easily be misread as 'has been blocked' which would make the user think the operation has been prevented for security reasons or that they are trying to do something they shouldn't...

Answer (score -1):

> "Your request has encountered a problem *beyond our scope*, and will not be retried."